# Where do processor's instructions resides ? in CPU cache or?

Tags: caching, cpu, instructions

My question is about CPU and its instructions. I know they have to be stored somewhere, so i would like to know where they are being stored ?  I suppose in cache...

Comment: Please refine your question a bit - or do some basic web research on that topic...

Comment: Dumitru you ask bootup-related questions in comments, you may want to read this excellent article by Gustavo Duartes: http://duartes.org/gustavo/blog/post/how-computers-boot-up - it explains how the CPU registers, including the instruction pointer, kick in when you power-on.

Answer (score 4):

In cache, and memory (for all of the programs instructions which may not be needed anytime soon).

The exact cache depends on the CPU. And cache is really just a general term used to describe any "memory" on the CPU chip, as opposed to on the separate RAM chip.

A modern CPU often has multiple caches. That means that the cache used for storing instructions is called an "instruction cache".

Information on caches in general can be found at Wikipedia - http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CPU_cache.

Comment: So You are saying from the moment i press the power button on my computer for the first time at the very same moment from somewhere? arrives Order -->see what instruction set the CPU have(in ns) and then that instructions are being pulled from the cpu cache to the RAM memory to some range of addresses? and then they are being stored and saved for the every every next moment of computer start-up!?

Comment: But aren't ram memories "cleaned" after you power off the computer. As i have understood only static ram could save the data for a long-er period of time..

Comment: @Dumitru mitru A CPU starts running instructions at a certain memory address when powered on. The hardware around the CPU usually wires that memory range to be a ROM or some other persistent memory storage., so the code starts executing from that ROM, which will typically load code from somewhere else into RAM, and start running that code. From the CPU point of view, it's all memory, and stuff loaded from memory might reside in a CPU cache once the CPU fetched the instructions from RAM.

Comment: so today there's no universal scheme on principle how processor makes it's way of work, or is that string universal more or less?

Comment: a lot of caching is dealt with by the processor. It impacts how fast code runs, but there isn't any way to directly control what gets cached, or what optimizations/predictions are made by the processor. The interface is only in what CPU instructions are available to use.

Comment: i mean, it's about the programmer/s who are making the chipset code "way of working" ?  ... these coders are working in sinergy with the manufacturers of hardware components so they could make a perfect code so they just upgrade the past principles with new ones ...

Comment: @Dumitru mitru Which chipsets are you talking about ? For peripheral devices, there's standard interfaces that the chips conform to, e.g. PCI, SATA, USB.

Comment: Generally speaking, the work of CPU princples are  mostly just being expanded all the time leaving the architecture of the Work principle intact... we are getting to the point of that it's all about the coders which are making that codes so they make the coding for the most of users(their  bought CPUs), i just very doubt that it couldn't get better then now.

Answer (score 2):

Some latest CPU's have something like a loop-cache(for decoded-instructions). When your critical loop is 64 bytes or smaller, then it is the fastest. Then there are outer-caches like L1-instruction cache and L2-L3 caches. The outermost home of the instructions is RAM. Of course they all are loaded from ROM, HDD, modem, floppy disc, cd-rom,.... Those are written with programming languages using a keyboard which is used to pass instructions/opinions in your mind. ----> Brain is the source, cache and cpu-registers are the last stop.

Comment: So You are saying from the moment i press the power button on my computer for the first time at the very same moment from somewhere? arrives Order -->see what instruction set the CPU have(in ns) and then that instructions are being pulled from the cpu cache to the RAM memory to some range of addresses? and then they are being stored and saved for the every every next moment of computer start-up!? 
 
But aren't ram memories "cleaned" after you power off the computer. As i have understood only static ram could save the data for a long-er period of time..

Comment: I meant the stabilized conditions such as "game loaded and running". Of course when you press power, first instructions are loaded from cpu-roms then rom of the computer then they make a structure in ram then cpu starts accessing hdd....

Comment: i have to note that i'm looking-analyzing from the biological sphere, ie. from the standpoint of the observer

Comment: I could understand that this Read-only memory is an electricity-powered set-of-instructions(codes) which are making the first steps in computer behaviour(in nanoseconds).

Comment: So the ROM is the first(1.) little coded thingy that starts the behaviour of CPU. The ROM resides in CPU cache, that's correct?

Comment: there are both in-cpu-rom and main-board-rom. of course in-cpu-rom are extremely small

Comment: @Dumitru mitru, No, a CPU cache is memory on the CPU chip, that is much, much faster than main memory, the CPU just uses a cache to run faster, as it can load/prefetch stuff from main memory into cache, and use that cache instead of fetching from main memory for every instruction. (There's data caches too, with the same principle)

Answer (score 0):

Instructions are data, just as data is data.  Everything in binary and everything is stored in RAM and everything is loaded from memory into the CPU (and on the way, is cached).  The CPU knows when it is loading instructions, rather than data, because the CPU knows what it is doing (e.g. I'm running this instruction now, I need to run this one next, I need to load it... ah, I'm loading an instruction).

Comment: So You are saying from the moment i press the power button on my computer for the first time at the very same moment from somewhere? arrives Order -->see what instruction set the CPU have(in ns) and then that instructions are being pulled from the cpu cache to the RAM memory to some range of addresses? and then they are being stored and saved for the every every next moment of computer start-up!?

Comment: But aren't ram memories "cleaned" after you power off the computer. As i have understood only static ram could save the data for a long-er period of time..

Comment: yes, but first the motherboard has to give the first contact with the cpu, when the first time is installed and had been set. Central processing unit would have to be the central processing unit, but the modus operandi is being set by the ???

Comment: So the ROM is the first(1.)electrically-powered little coded thingy that starts the behaviour of CPU. The ROM resides in CPU cache, that's correct?

Comment: Look on-line for some primers on PC design.  When power is applied, the motherboard initializes itself, the BIOS kicks in, the CPU begins executing code from a pre-defined location in memory, boot-strapping occurs, eventually the OS begins to load.  Initially, the CPU will be executing (if I recall correctly) from ROM which has been copied into RAM.